# Why codedeploy show this error AccessDeniedException in the logs of AWS in Ubuntu 22?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

0

i install correctly with the script in the last comment, but the logs of code deploy in the instance show this error:

2022-09-12 17:53:57 INFO [codedeploy-agent(2538)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.4.0-2218_deb. 2022-09-12 17:53:57 INFO [codedeploy-agent(2538)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 400 0.023022 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:898670725295:instance/i-0075f52e02798a59e") Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::AccessDeniedException Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::AccessDeniedException

someone knows what it the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/331

Please,Try checking `codedeploy-agent.aws_wire.log`.

reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-agent-configuration.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).